# When would a python pool freeblock have been assigned 0xffffffff

Tags: python, memory-management, gdb, pool

I have met a Python Segmentation fault when developoing a python c module.
After debugging, it turns out that one of the pools current using has freeblock set to be 0xffffffff.

Core Dump gdb frames:

```
(gdb) frame 0
#0  Py0bject_Malloc (nbytes=53) at../Objects/obmalloc.c:837
837 in ../Objects/obmalloc.c
(gdb) p bp
$6 = (block *) Oxffffffffffffffff <error: Cannot access memory at address Oxffffffffffffffff>
```

> for Better colored text, still provide gdb screen shots here.
> [image]

Relative code:

```py
void *PyObject_Malloc(size_t nbytes) {
    ...

    /*
     * This implicitly redirects malloc(0).
     */
    if ((nbytes - 1) < SMALL_REQUEST_THRESHOLD) {
        LOCK();
        /*
         * Most frequent paths first
         */
        size = (uint)(nbytes - 1) >> ALIGNMENT_SHIFT;
        pool = usedpools[size + size];
        if (pool != pool->nextpool) {
            /*
             * There is a used pool for this size class.
             * Pick up the head block of its free list.
             */
            ++pool->ref.count;
            bp = pool->freeblock;
            assert(bp != NULL);
            if ((pool->freeblock = *(block **)bp) != NULL) {
                UNLOCK();
                return (void *)bp;
            }

    ...
}
```

A above have shown, it pick value that `pool's freeblock(bp)` point to while bp is 0xffffffff which violates our cognization to python memory management.

So the question is, when and why, would the freeblock pointer have been assigned with 0xffffffff?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that i have not use gil properly, and somewhere multithreading error has been triggered. Then the freeblock's value has been wrong.